# Clear `PagingDataAdapter` between refresh calls

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, android-paging-3

I am using the Paging 3 `PagingDataAdapter` to search the database based on the given query.
Every time a new query is submitted, i call the `refresh()` method on the adapter. The problem is that until the new data is loaded, the old one is still present.

Is there a way to remove all items from the list so that no items are present when loading is in progress? Also, I use the `ConcatAdapter` to attach a header and a footer to indicate loading, so my goal is to have only the progress indicator showing when the data is being loaded/new query is submitted.

**Update:**

The only way i managed to make it work was to call `adapter.submitData(PagingData.empty())` followed by `pagingSource.invalidate()`. I don't like this solution because it is not easy to gain access to `invalidate()` method which is available in repository layer and I had to use it in the `ViewModel`. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? I don't think that is a way to do so, because the use case of refreshing a list and removing items during the load is quite common and I thought it was taken into account during Paging 3 library development.

Answer (score 0):

actually, I was forced to clear the cache and reload the data once again from the room side not Paging side I know there is a better solution but this a temp solution